# PHP Mysql Aborted Function

Tags: php, mysql

So my problem/question is i'm coding a irc bot and that bot make some request to sql but some times i need to restart the mysql and script losse the connection and display.
PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

I already tried to use "connection_aborted()" but it always return 0
tested with connected script and disconnected script i'm trying to check when he dc's to auto reconnect again but that function keep returning 0

Comment: `connection_aborted()` has nothing to do with MySQL :)

Comment: Can u tell what can i use to detect when script disconnect from sql ?

Comment: Already find how to detect the connection 

    if(mysql_ping($con))
    {
        echo "Alive Connection";
    }elseif(!mysql_ping($con)){
        echo "Lost Connection";
        //reconnecting to sql
        mysql_close($con);
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if (!$con) {
            die('cant connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("db", $con);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbname');
$ping=mysqli_ping($link);
if ($ping) {
    printf ("mysqli is connected");
} else {
    printf ("mysqli is NOT connected");
}
```